# Redirect after clicking download link in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link in my page that downloads a PDF file however after they have clicked either of the download links, I would like to take them to another page.

The page gives them one of 2 choices for selecting a download file but I only wish to allow them to make one choice and then exit to another page.

My code is as follows:

```
<div class="columns medium-6">
    <h3 class="text-center">7 Tips for Creating a <br />Happy Workplace</h3> <img src="https://www.maylake.com.au/_assets/images/mini-guide/bookcover-7-tips-workplace.png" height="250px" alt="7 Tips for Creating a Happy Workplace eBook">
    <p style="font-size: 18px;" class="text-center">Discover how you can make your workplace a healthier environment by simply making being a happy place to work for everyone</p>
    <div class="choose">
        <input type="radio" name="choice-books" id="choice-7-tips">
        <label>I would like to receive a copy of the eBook</label>
        <div class="reveal-if-active">
            <p class="text-center"><a href="/LiteratureRetrieve.aspx?ID=192014" class="button radius text-center">DOWNLOAD Now</a> </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="columns medium-6">
    <h3 class="text-center">Your Short Guide to Leasing a Commercial Office Space</h3> <img src="https://www.maylake.com.au/_assets/images/mini-guide/bookcover-leasing-commercial-office.png" alt="Guide to Leasing Commercial Office" height="250">
    <p style="font-size: 18px;" class="text-center">Understand what you should be considering before leasing any commercial office space. Being forewarned and prepared could save you lots
        of money and grief</p>
    <div class="choose">
        <input type="radio" name="choice-books" id="choice-leasing">
        <label for="choice-leasing">I would like to receive a copy of the eBook</label>
        <div class="reveal-if-active">
            <p class="text-center"><a href="/LiteratureRetrieve.aspx?ID=192012" class="button radius text-center">DOWNLOAD Now</a> </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Suggest you open a dialog or modify existing html when they click those links and expose link to page you want them to continue to. There is no way to track download status using javascript in the window

Answer (score 1):

I would change your `a` elements to something like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="/LiteratureRetrieve.aspx?ID=192014" class="button radius text-center" onclick="window.location='http://google.com';">DOWNLOAD Now</a>
```

This will take them to google.com at the same time they are downloading the pdf.